# How to store multiple ParseFile objects in single ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

My question is very similar to this post
"[storing multiple ParseFile objects in single ParseObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633977/storing-multiple-parsefile-objects-in-single-parseobject)", but can't resolve it on my own

```
ParseObject pObject = new ParseObject();    
ArrayList<ParseFile> pFileList = new ArrayList<ParseFile>();
for (String thumbPath : thumbList) {
   byte[] imgData = convertFileToByteArray(thumbPath);
   ParseFile pFile = new ParseFile("mediaFiles",imgData);
   pFileList.add(pFile);    
}

   pObject.addAll("mediaFiles", pFileList); 
   pObject.saveEventually();
```

> And Hector Ramos answered the question:Try uploading the ParseFiles using the save method before associating them with the Parse Object.

Can anyone tell me how to change this piece of code? appreciate any kindly help.

Comment: this is the error I got from android studio: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile.

Comment: Problem solved, just added pFile.save()